# How is the less-than (<) operator for dictionaries defined in Python 2?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

In Python 2 you can compare dictionaries with the less-than and greater-than operators, meaning that they can be sorted/ordered:

```py
>>> {'a': 2} < {'a': 3}
True
>>> {'a': 7} < {'a': 3}
False
>>> {'b': 4} > {'c': 1}
False
>>> sorted([{'c': 1}, {'a': 5}, {'b':2 }])
[{'a': 5}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 1}]
```

In Python 3 you cannot do that:

```py
>>> {'a': 2} < {'a': 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
>>> sorted([{'c': 1}, {'a': 5}, {'b':2 }])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

- How are the dictionaries compared in Python 2? (how is the `<`-operator defined?)
- And when was this change introduced? (which specific version? And why?)

Comment: Not sure if its a duplicate -- of that question atleast

Comment: At least based on your example, it looks like you compare them item by item, where each item is a tuple consisting of a key and its value. Since there's no guaranteed order in which you would *get* those items, you couldn't reliably compare two dicts. (*Maybe* they would be sorted by key first, but that assumes there is a defined sort order on the keys.) Python 3 probably wisely decided to drop whatever arbitrary ordering was previously used.

Comment: Also, just like `+`, there are several ways you might consider comparing two dictionaries: by size, by order of their keys, by order of their values, etc. Better to provide *no* built-in support than to pick an implementation arbitrarily.

Comment: The only answer I know is "Why dict comparison was removed" — I'll quote the OP _"How are the dictionaries compared?"_.